neither my Design view nor any Android Virtual Devices Will Display anything
I am in the process of taking the Android Basics with Compose course on the Android developers' site. I've hit a speed bump the last ten days or so: whenever I try to open the split design view (or the regular design view) nothing displays. I am working on the (very easy) "Birthday Card" project which is supposed to display, "Happy Birthday, Megan" with a padding and background, and it won't even show that.
It was working around two weeks ago.
Here's what I have tried so far:

Re-installing Android Studio (I've done this twice).
Not using a preferred directory where I would like to save my android development stuff, and simply using the default folders to save.
Deleting previous android studio assignments and "experiments" (there were only two or three) in the hopes that eliminating some other code from influencing the current code.

Here's what I am using:

An HP Laptop running Windows 11
8 GB of RAM, upgradable to 32 GB
Android Studio Iguana | 2023.2.1 Patch 1

What to do? I want to continue the Android Basics with Compose course, and I'm hoping to begin a Coursera course in about a month and want to be ready. In the meantime, I have been going through the Kotlin 13-week code lab on IntelliJ to get better in pure Kotlin. But I need to get into Compose soon.
Edit: adding 1) a screenshot
Android Studio preview pane not loading
and 2) the simple code I want to run:
package com.example.happybirthday

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material3.Surface
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import com.example.happybirthday.ui.theme.HappyBirthdayTheme

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            HappyBirthdayTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    Greeting("Android")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun Greeting(name: String, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    Text(
        text = "Hello $name!",
        modifier = modifier
    )
}

@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun GreetingPreview() {
    HappyBirthdayTheme {
        Greeting("Android")
    }
}


You need to add a screenshoot or tow of your Android Studio, in addition you need to share your code to help understand your problem.

As you advised, I added a screen and the code I am trying to run. Thanks for replying.

does it stay in the in loading state like for ever ?

I had the same issue, silly enough I realized I was zoomed out so much that  the text was not visible in my preview pane. Did you try playing with the zoom controls?

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
